# IIS HTTPS sites

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, self-signed-certificate

I have ASP systems and APIs hosted on IIS, some of these sites need to bind with HTTPS. In order to bind them, I use a Self-Signed Certificate. The issue is that Browser considers it as untrusted and shows certificate invalid errors.
[This is from Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0B2U.png). 
Searching the internet, the solution was to buy a certificate from a trusted provider like [ssl.com](https://www.ssl.com/). My question is: 
 Do I need to buy a real **Domain Name** so that I can purchase an SSL certificate to authenticate my site/sites? 
I don't want to buy a Domain for every server I have, isn't there another way to authenticate my site/sites. 
 Also I can't import the Self-Signed Certificate at the client side because there my be 100 users.
 Thanks

Comment: "I don't want to buy a Domain for every server I have" indicates that you are more suitable to set up your own CA with active directory and issue your own certificates for your servers and users as long as they are in the same active directory.

Comment: The suggestion from @LexLi would work if every client for these servers are in your control in order to install the CA certificate. Even in case they are not, you do not have to buy a new domain for every server, but you can use sub domains in `hostname.example.com` pattern. Also, Let's Encrypt certificates are free.

Comment: This isn't a forum "should my web site have a certificate".

Answer (score 0):

1. SSL Certificate doesn't authenticate just secure the comunication between client and server. it's possible use Apache/Nginx to request some kind of authentication.
2. If you have a single domain you could buy a Wild Card Certificate(*.example.com). If is not possible buy it you can use Let's Encrypt Certificates that supports wild card certificates, but you need renew it every 3 months.
3. That is one of the problems when you use Self-Signed Certificate. To install the self-signed certificate you could use Active Directory policy to deploy the Cert massively